# (new mobile chat UI) Make "replied to" arrows tappable

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, mobile-web

In the new, opt-in mobile chat UI, each replying message has a back-arrow in it indicating that it's a reply. Tapping that arrow highlights and scrolls to the referent message, the one that was replied to. Alas, the arrow is so tiny that it's nearly impossible to tap. And, unlike with many Web pages (e.g. SE), I can't unpinch the screen to zoom in (which would make the arrow appear larger so I could tap it). (I'm running Safari `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E238 Safari/601.1` (and the same happens in Opera Mini) on an iPhone 5S with iOS9.) Can you please either (1) make the arrow larger or (2) allow us to unpinch the screen to zoom in?

---

I just spent fully a minute trying and failing to tap the little arrow. I finally, instead, selected the post, clicked the edit link (only because I'm a moderator), found the responded-to message's number in the source code, left the room, went to the transcript, and appended that number to the URL as an anchor. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: The title makes no sense, since the arrow is tappable already. Plus, opera mini is not supported by SE. Use a real browser app, e.g. Chrome or Firefox. (or even Safari, which comes built-in with iPhone devices)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I was kinda assuming the same problem existed in other browsers also, but will check. I also have never AFAIR seen a list of supported or unsupported browsers for SE chat; where is that list? As to the title, I suppose I could add "really" or "actually", but I don't think it's necessary: the arrow is, practically speaking, currently not clickable.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I've edited.

Comment: [This is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipnUn.png), Chrome in android device. Big enough in my opinion, and never had any issues. Making it bigger will just ruin the design in my opinion, though I don't see any harm in supporting option to zoom in. As for supported browsers, it's clearly mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) that Opera Mini is not supported, and chat is part of SE.

Comment: Maybe adding a screenshot of what you see will help your case.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I'm not sure what good a screenshot will do, since people will see the same number of pixels as larger or smaller than I do. However, I'll try to measure the arrow in millimeters; alternatively, perhaps someone can compute that size from a known image size and pixels-per-inch number.

Comment: Screenshot should show the size of the arrow compared to size of text. Hmm... maybe you have big font on your device, hence the arrow appear small to you?

Comment: (Toward my preceding comment, the iPhone 5S supposedly has 326 ppi.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, the size relative to text doesn't matter: that doesn't make the arrow harder or easier to tap. It's the actual size of the arrow that matters. In any event, I haven't customized any font settings on the phone.)

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283295